# Why this Code is throwing ClassCastException in java Spring MVC

Tags: java, exception, spring-mvc

I am working on *Spring 2.5 MVC Module*, I am retriving the data from the database using template and it is returning list ... In the list I have added bean Objects and now when i try to retrieve the values from bean objects its showing `ClassCastException`

```
  List listLogin = LoginDao.Authenticate(username,password);
  Iterator it = listLogin.iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) 
  {
       Login  bean1= (Login) it.next(); //here it is showing classCastException 
       System.out.println(bean1.getClinicId());
  }

  public static List  Authenticate(String userName, String password) {
      List names = template.query("select clinicId from doc_user where userName='"+userName+"' and passwd='"+password+"'", 
           new RowMapper() {
               public Object mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException 
               {
                    ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();
                    Login loginBean = new Login();
                    loginBean.setClinicId(String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt(1)));
                    lst.add(loginBean);
                    return lst;
                }
       });
       return names;
   }
```

Comment: As a note, in the future it would be helpful to also post the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 2):

That would be because whatever `(Login) it.next()` is returning is not a `Login` Object. YOu could either use a debugger and step trough and see what it is returning or do the poor man's version and print it out, to see what it is returning:

```
while (it.hasNext()) 
  {
       Object  bean1=  it.next(); 
       System.out.println(bean1.getClass().getName());
  }
```

**UPDATE based on your comments:**

You know that is is returning a list that contains a list of your login objects:

```
while (it.hasNext()) 
{
   List  list1 =  (List)it.next(); 
   for (Object bean : list1) {
       System.out.println(((Login)bean).getClinicId());
   }
}
```

I will say I think you are doing something wrong, and that your query should probably just be returning a list of Logins to begin with. Because it seems like it ArrayList in the parent list will only contain one object so you could probably do:

```
public static List  Authenticate(String userName, String password) {
      List names = template.query("select clinicId from doc_user where userName='"+userName+"' and passwd='"+password+"'", 
           new RowMapper() {
               public Object mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException 
               {
                    Login loginBean = new Login();
                    loginBean.setClinicId(String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt(1)));
                    return loginBean ;
                }
       });
       return names;
}
```

And then process them with the code you originally thought would work:

```
List listLogin = LoginDao.Authenticate(username,password);

Iterator it = listLogin.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
   Login  bean1= (Login) it.next(); 
   System.out.println(bean1.getClinicId());
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your Answer Mr jschoen... I knew that it is returning ArrayList Class type . But, the Thing is that In this List Objects I stored Bean Object or Objects, Now I want to Retrive Objects Property Values ... Thank you

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Are you saying you return a list of objects that are of a mixed type? Some are Lists, some are of the `Login` type, etc. If that is the case, have you considered returning a Map of those values instead of a list. It would make it easier to get the one you want. The other (probably better option) is to create a new class to hold those properties and return that single object.

Comment: In the Code "lst" is an ArrayList Object

Comment: Ya it is somewhat like what only Objects are Mixed Up. Bean Objects of type Login are Added in ArrayList Object and  that Bean Object(loginBean here) has clinicId as an Variable And Now I want to retrieve data from that Variable cliniId

Comment: Thank you Mr jschoen, The code of iterating upon the List Object(list1) getting List Object content that is Bean Object and upon Bean iterating using enhanced for loop to get clinicId is working ...